# Search by two entities doesn't work with JpaRepository

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, pageable

I'm making an app that holds a UserProfile with Wallet that has many Transactions.

Here's the Transaction class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions")
public class Transaction extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "amount", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @Column(name = "executed_on", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime executedOn;

    @Column(name = "is_top_up")
    private boolean isTopUp;

    @Column(name = "note")
    private String note;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = UserProfile.class)
    private UserProfile sender;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = UserProfile.class)
    private UserProfile receiver;

    public Transaction() {
    }
```

Here's the Wallet class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "wallets")
public class Wallet extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Transaction.class, cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "wallets_transactions",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "wallet_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<Transaction> transactions;

    public Wallet() {
        this.transactions = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public Set<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void setTransactions(Set<Transaction> transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }

    public void addTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
        this.transactions.add(transaction);
    }
}
```

What I want is, to get all transactions by sender and receiver search criteria. For example, user 'A' sent money to user 'B'. I'm using JpaRepository. The end result should be in a `Page<Transaction>` class.

So far, when using just `findAllBySender(UserProfile sender, Pageable pageable)`, it does work and I get the exact right Transactions. But when I try `Page<Transaction> findAllBySenderAndReceiver(UserProfile sender, UserProfile receiver, Pageable pageable);` I get a `Page<T>` with 0 elements when my DB has test data with at least 1 record.

Comment: Try logging queries to the database and look at them if they are correct.

Comment: Are your sender and receiver same in the test data ?

Comment: @SB Hello. No. I'm using two different records of the UserProfile class.

Comment: Do check if the UserProfile entities need to have an implementation for hashcode and equals.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Turns out, I had a logical error. Thank you all, for your assistance.